# open form from another mdichild form and make it mdi child C# - winform

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I have facing a problem in my application.
I have a MainForm which is MDIPARENT
and a login form which is MDICHILD
the problem which i was facing is when
i login as a user with correct details
then my login form is dispose. the problem
is when login is dispose i want to open another
form F2 which is mdichild.  following code doesn't work
at all.

```
Form1 F1 = new Form();

F1.mdiparent = this; 

F1.show();
```

the code above runs a new instance of a form and doesn't 
make it mdi.

Comment: Is `f1` your login form? if so, use `ShowDialog`, then depending on the return value of this (DialogResult), act accordingly

Comment: `Form1 F1 = new Form1();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show the MDIParent form first then at the Form_Load event show the login form using ShowDialog method. Once login is successful the login form will unload it self since it is just a Dialog form. Then instantiate the  other form you want to show.